# found: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] required: Option[?]

Tags: scala

I have written this code

```
def m1(x: Int) = Future { if (x % 2 == 0) Some(x) else None }
def m2(x: Int) = Future { if (x % 2 != 0) Some(x) else None }

for {
  x <- Some(3)
  x1 <- m1(x)
  x2 <- m2(x)
} yield x1 orElse x2
```

My objective is that the code should first open the future of m1 and if that has a some, then use that value. otherwise, it should open the future of m2 and use that value.

But it keeps getting a compile time error

```
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]
 required: Option[?]
       x1 : Option[Int] <- m1(x)

                    ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the for comprehension the first element obtained from the generator - `x` - is an `Option`, while the others are `Future`s. Unfortunately Scala doesn't support having different generator types in the same for comprehension and you would need a monad transformer to achieve this.

The simple way is just to wrap the Option in a Future:

```scala
for {
  Some(x) <- Future.successful(Some(3))
  x1 <- m1(x)
  x2 <- m2(x)
} yield x1 orElse x2
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is not the same as the code which I wrote. m1 and m2 accept an Int ... not Some(int)

Comment: Right, you could use pattern matching to get the value only if it's present. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: If you go this way, consider using `Future.successful(Some(3))` instead of `Future(Some(3))`. The latter introduces unnecessary asynchronous boundary and requires presence of `ExecutionContext`, whereas the former just constructs a ready successful `Future` instance.

Comment: @Haspemulator thanks, that's a good suggestion. I will update the code with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because for expression is being translated to chain of `flatMap`, `map`, `filter`, `withFilter` and `foreach` method calls. Generally speaking expression:

```
for {
  x <- X
  y <- Y
} yield yourCode(x, y)
```

Is translated to code somewhat similar to the following:

```
X.flatMap(x => Y.map(y => yourFunc(x, y))
```

I simplified it a bit, in reality partial function are used but general idea remains the same.
Option has the following signature of `flatMap` method:

```
def flatMap[B](f : A => Option[B]): Option[B]
def flatMap[B](f : A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): Option[B]
```

Future is not an Option instance nor GenTraversableOnce so it is impossible to use for comprehension for it, your code after transformation looks similar to the following:

```
Some(3).flatMap(x => m1(x).flatMap(x1 => m2(x1).map(x2 => x1 orElse x2)))
```

Type of `m1(x).flatMap(x1 => m2(x1).map(x2 => x1 orElse x2))` is `Future[Option[Int]]` which does not conform to the `flatMap` signature.
I hope my answer will help understand for comprehension.